# Remove part of a JSON ArrayBuffer

Tags: arrays, json, scala, arraybuffer

Firstly, Play JSON is not an option unfortunately.

I know how to remove & add elements in an ArrayBuffer, e.g. the below removes elements "b" & "c"...

```
val x = ArrayBuffer('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')

x -= ('b', 'c')
```

Giving
`x = ArrayBuffer('a', 'd', 'e')`

However, I have a JSON Array, something like below, where I want to remove "c" & "d" that exists in each dictionary within the list of dictionaries of "z".

```
ArrayBuffer({"x":1,"y":2,"z":[{"a":0.5,"b":"North","c":[{"c1":1,"c2":195.00,"c3":null},{"c1":2,"c2":229.00,"c3":null}],"d":{"d1":"N","d2":null}},{"a":0.5,"b":"North","c":[{"c1":1,"c2":195.00,"c3":null},{"c1":2,"c2":229.00,"c3":null}],"d":{"d1":"N","d2":null}},{"a":0.5,"b":"North","c":[{"c1":1,"c2":195.00,"c3":null},{"c1":2,"c2":229.00,"c3":null}],"d":{"d1":"N","d2":null}}]
```

Is this possible?
If so could you point me in the right direction - would be very grateful!
Thank you

Comment: What's the type of elements in the array? Show valid scala code that creates that sample array from your snippet.

Comment: Also, don't use mutable collections.